# Publish issue with own domain and IONOS hosting ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, deployment, publish, visual-studio-2022

I have some sliught issues with deploying a webforms application from VS2022 publish tool.

I have the website and I want the site to be shown on the main domain which is [www.newroyvemour.co.uk](http://www.newroyvemour.co.uk).

The issue is that on the main domain I have an error message:

[This is the error message I can see on the main domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu6eZ.png)

Does anybody know how to publish the site to be on the main domain?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What makes you think it's not published to the right spot? Did you read the error message? Do you understand why you're seeing it? Did you make sure you have a published file that matches the default document?

Comment: Did you see the image I posted? I do not understand what that error message is about. Do you know anybody or could you help me to solve this issue on Discord please? I do not really know how to setup the IIS manager default document I am beginner in ASP.NET just want to do my own website as I do not like the website builders out there. If you give me your Discord I will send you a request and we can talk.

Comment: I sure did.  Please answer each of the questions I asked you in the previous comment. No, I will not help you on Discord. We're here on Stack Overflow. If you don't want to use Stack Overflow, then don't use it. But if you're going to come here and use it, then make sure you address all comments and provide enough information so we can help you.

Comment: Okay, if you don't know how to set the default document...did you look at what the hosting manager provides you? Did you look around for a way to set a default document? What page within your website (filename) do you expect a user to reach when the visit the root of your site?

Comment: I have fixed it, the issue was that when I published the site on the hosting I had to leave the path empty and with this the main domain is the one where the site is stored. Sorry if I was rude, it just got me really frustrated.